# Read table border lines in a PDF file using PoDoFo

Tags: c++, podofo

I need to extract coordinates and other info of table border lines using PoDoFo C++ library. I need this information to extract a table with text from a PDF file.

I cannot attach the file itself as it contains my personal information but I'll be attaching a screenshot(personal info is erased).

[image: This is an example of a table inside the PDF file]

I tried searching PoDoFo library documentation to extract any information about elements of the PDF but did not found anything. At this moment I can only extract text with built-in PoDoFo API but only position information it contains is coordinates(bounding box is always non present).

Comment: Ask questions like this on the forum of the library (developers)

Comment: there doesn't seem to be a forum for PoDoFo